# Error: expected expression in C — Can't define a variable as a length of an array

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I'm taking CS courses, and wrote a simple program to find an average of the given (input) amount of inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("Please enter the number of scores: ");

    int scores = [n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int scores[i] = get_int("Please, enter the score: ");
    }
    printf("Average: %f\n", average(n, scores));
}

float average(int length, int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sum += sum + array[i];

    }
    return sum / (float)length;
}
```

When compiling, "expected expression" error occurs on line 10 (i.e. `{int scores = [n];}` —
any help or suggestions would be appreciated!!

Comment: Did you read the C reference on how to declare an array variable? Or even just search "declare array in C"?

Comment: @kaylum, sort of. I may be silly at the moment, I learn with practice. I just tried it my-self and compiler showed an error, which I couldn't understand. Please even if answer is easy, tell me)

Comment: `sum += sum + array[i];`is probably not what you want when calculating the average.

Comment: @anastaciu ohh yes "sum+=" = "sum = sum + ..." thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid syntax:

```
int scores = [n];
```

If you want to define `scores` as an array of size `n` you want:

```
int scores[n];
```

Also, this doesn't do what you might expect:

```
int scores[i] = get_int("Please, enter the score: ");
```

This creates an array called `scores` of size `i`, masking the array defined previously, and attempts to initialize it with a single value instead of a list of values.  If you want to assign to the existing array you want:

```
scores[i] = get_int("Please, enter the score: ");
```

Comment: @_dbush add also list of the good C books. IMO it is what OP needs.